# Where to save the icon and how to replace the cart?

Tags: magento2, theme, icon

I know there are some topics on this subject, but my question is the following, not only do I need to know how to replace the cart icon, but I need to use a png image I have. Where do I save this image in my theme so that I can only reference it in the same way that luma makes reference to its icons?

I wanted to do it by css, I saw that I can change it as follows:

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before {
content: ''; }
```

Luma:

```
font-family: 'luma-icons';
```

But how do I call my image that I need to save my theme? and again, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your cart image in /pub/media/

On your theme:

**web/css/source/_extend.less**

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart::before {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #8f8f8f;    
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  speak: none;
  text-align: center;
  content: url('https://www.yourdomin.com/yourstore/pub/media/Cart.png');
}

.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart::active {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #8f8f8f;    
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  speak: none;
  text-align: center;
  content: url('https://www.yourdomin.com/yourstore/pub/media/Cart.png');
}

.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart.active:before {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #757575;
  content: url('https://www.yourdomin.com/yourstore/pub/media/Cart.png');
  font-family: 'luma-icons';
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  speak: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your image in below path.

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<package>/web/images/cart_image.png
```

Now you need to add `<span class="cartimg">` tag just before the `<a>` tag of cart icon and apply your png image to span tag.

if your css in the below folder

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<package>/web/css/style.css
```

Then you can write

```
.cartimg { background: url('../images/cart_image.png') }
```

for the updated answer please check below image.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't find where the phtml with the tag <a> of the cart is, did you know the directory?

Comment: Hi Hudson, Please check my updated answer. The <a> was also in my custom theme where you have to override this html and add <span> tag just above <a> tag as mention in screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can put your cart png image on below path

app/design/frontend/{{VENDOR}}/{{PACKAGE}}/web/images

Add css in your style

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart {
    font-size: 0;
}

.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before {
    content: "";
    background: url(../images/cart-ico.png) no-repeat;
    width: 24px;
    height: 27px;
}
```